# Behaviour Of Local Variables In A Multi-Threaded Method In VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, spinlock

The code below is part of an example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-use-spinlock-for-low-level-synchronization). It is the example on how to use `SpinLock` but to *my eye* there is a race condition in it.
Why I think this is because of the `Dim lockTaken As Boolean = False` line in the `UpdateWithSpinLock` method. It appears to me that the following could occur:

Thread 1 enters `UpdateWithSpinLock` method and executes as far as `_queue.Enqueue(d)` and a context switch occurs.
Thread 1 now has the `SpinLock` and `lockTaken` is True.
Thread 2 enters and only executes as far as the line `Dim lockTaken As Boolean = False`.
Thread 2 has now set `lockTaken` back to False and a context switch occurs.
Thread 1 continues and tests `lockTaken` in the `Finally` block and finds it to be False (it should be True for Thread 1) so doesn't release the `SpinLock`.
Thread 1 exits the method leaving the lock inplace and thread 2 waiting forever.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Class SpinLockDemo2

    Const N As Integer = 100000
    Shared _queue = New Queue(Of Data)()
    Shared _lock = New Object()
    Shared _spinlock = New SpinLock()

    Class Data
        Public Name As String
        Public Number As Double
    End Class

    Shared Sub Main()
        UseSpinLock()

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub UpdateWithSpinLock(ByVal d As Data, ByVal i As Integer)

        Dim lockTaken As Boolean = False
        Try
            _spinlock.Enter(lockTaken)
            _queue.Enqueue(d)
        Finally

            If lockTaken Then
                _spinlock.Exit(False)
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub UseSpinLock()
        Dim sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        Parallel.Invoke(
               Sub()
                   For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
                       UpdateWithSpinLock(New Data() With {.Name = i.ToString(), .Number = i}, i)
                   Next
               End Sub,
                Sub()
                    For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
                        UpdateWithSpinLock(New Data() With {.Name = i.ToString(), .Number = i}, i)
                    Next
                End Sub
            )
        sw.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine("elapsed ms with spinlock: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is the way I'm interpreting this correct. If it's not could you please show me what I'm missing.

Comment: Looks like you try to program semaphores new, which do lock and waiting at kernel level

Comment: You assume the Boolean is shared by all threads.  It is not, local variables and method arguments have distinct values for each thread.  They are stored on the stack, each thread has its own stack.  Shared doesn't change that.  The only role of lockTaken is to ensure the lock is released again, even when the thread got aborted by Thread.Abort or an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant   Ah got it, thanks Hans I understand now that helps alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that code, `lockTaken` is a local variable so no instance of that method running in one thread could change the value of that variable in another instance of the method running on a different thread. What you're describing would require that `lockTaken` was a member variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what's confusing me is that the `UpdateWithSpinLock` method is shared so isn't every thread using the same "instance" of the method therefor setting and resetting the same `lockTaken`?

Comment: @CodeAdze, if the method were not `Shared` and you called it multiple times on the same object, would you expect the local variables to be shared across calls? I'm guessing not, so why should a `Shared` method behave differently? `Shared` just means one for the type rather than one per instance of the type. Each method call is still independent though.

Comment: _... would you expect the local variables to be shared across calls? I'm guessing not..._   unfortunately that's where my misunderstanding was. I didn't know, as @Hanns Passant explained, that each thread had it's own stack and local variable values so I thought that if thread2 entered a method before thread1 had exited then thread2 would start re-setting local variable values that thread1 was still manipulating. I had a feeling that I misunderstood something as my thinking was causing me to grab `SyncLock`s all the time which basically made my supposedly parallel code execute synchronously.

Comment: `Shared` means that the routine does not run in the context of a single instance of the class---unlike with a normal member routine, there is no `Me`.  It still has access to private and protected members (given an instance either as an argument, constructed internally, or obtained in some other way).  It doesn't change anything about how the routine's own variables behave.  If you were to access any `Shared` variables or if you were to access anything on a shared instance, you could still run into races.